# Ubuntu Server 14.04.4 server setup

Tags: performance, cpu

Need some help on my configuration on my low power server. I have a multiple applications loaded on my  ASRock Q1900M Intel Quad-Core Celeron Processor with 4GB memory and 2 TB WD green drive. The apps are openvpn server, newznab , sickrage and couch potato. I have notice many times that phyton2.7 takes more than 100% of the cpu power and that just kills my newznab server. My overall CPU usage is low (around 40%) as it has 4 cores. I have yet to see all four cores go over 80% at one given time. It keeps bouncing back and forth between usage. I have changed my CPU governance = Performance, I have used the nice command on my sql and php programs.

I have done a stress test on all cpu and they do go to 100% each but for some reason I feel the server is not utilizing all its CPU power to keep all applications functioning effectively.

I am looking for assistance to see if there is anything I can do or configure to make the hardware use its full potential to leverage all its CPU power to work on tasks.

```
top - 11:19:39 up 14:23,  1 user,  load average: 2.97, 2.77, 2.44
Tasks: 142 total,   3 running, 139 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu0  : 20.1 us,  3.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 56.1 id, 18.5 wa,  0.0 hi,  2.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu1  : 62.6 us,  1.3 sy,  0.0 ni, 25.6 id, 10.4 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu2  : 50.3 us,  3.4 sy,  0.0 ni, 45.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  1.0 si,  0.0 st
%Cpu3  : 26.3 us,  3.0 sy,  0.0 ni, 70.3 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.3 si,  0.0 st
KiB Mem:   3746500 total,  3539160 used,   207340 free,   117464 buffers
KiB Swap:  3888124 total,   315412 used,  3572712 free.  2396332 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
11986 gemnis    20   0  357312 115208  15780 R  84.0  3.1   7:52.95 php5
 2761 gemnis    20   0 2775840 251720   7184 S  72.7  6.7 271:08.37 python2.7
 1556 mysql      1 -19 1235804 249436   8312 S  17.9  6.7 100:01.81 mysqld
  827 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   2.7  0.0   2:58.56 cifsd
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.7  0.0   1:06.96 rcu_sched
12090 gemnis    20   0   24972   3028   2504 R   0.7  0.1   0:00.12 top
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:29.79 rcuos/0
   25 root      20   0       0      0      0 R   0.3  0.0   0:46.38 rcuos/2
  163 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0.3  0.0   0:18.67 jbd2/sda1-8
 2071 openvpn+  20   0  160592  31256   2912 S   0.3  0.8   0:19.43 python
 3525 gemnis    20   0 2204244  85652   6352 S   0.3  2.3  13:14.86 python
```

Thx u

Answer (score 0):

First up, you should figure out what python2.7 is actually doing there. Running "ps -ef" should give you a process listing with full commands for each process.

Anyways, I strongly suspect that the server *is* using all its potential CPU power when it can. Your problems are likely (a) it's underpowered for what you're trying to do, and/or (b) there's another bottleneck (if you're performing operations that are heavy on filesystem I/O, for example, your Western Digital Green drive may simply not be fast enough and may be the bottleneck).

Comment: My assumption is that the phyton2.7 is being used by sickrage and that is when it is searching for shows. I tried ur ps-ef command but not sure how to paste all that info on this comment box =-). If I switch to a SSD drive for this box, will it make a huge difference?

Comment: If the problem is indeed filesystem I/O related, then yeah, it may indeed make a huge difference. It's entirely possible that my guess is incorrect, but at least to me it seems the most likely scenario.

BTW, you can always use https://paste.ubuntu.com/ to paste longer logs or console output or such.